# Set session id on all my domains after logging into one of my sites on the same server

Tags: php, session

I am using PHP's [session_set_save_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to store the session data in my MySQL database from domain1.com.
I want to write the session id to domain2.com automatically so that the user doesn't have to login again with the same credentials on domain2.com
So I tried doing this but it didn't work.
`setcookie("sessid", $id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", "domain2.com");`
Is there a way to auto set the same session ids to my other domains which is a network of sites sharing the same database and www folder ? (All domains on my virtual hosts point to the same directory)
An example would be stakoverflow.com - After logging in, if I goto askubuntu.com, the header would automatically populate with my details.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
setcookie($key, $value, time() + $time, '/', 'carbonphp.com', true, true);
```

where [carbonphp.com](https://carbonphp.com) #shamelessPlug is your domain, or possibly localhost.

function [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

```
/** Cookies are a pain to set up as they also rely on headers not being sent.
 *  This method makes setting cookies easy with three params.
 * @param string $key the name of the cookie
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param int $time the expiration time of our cookie
 */
public static function setCookie(string $key, $value = null, int $time = 604800): void // Week?
{
    if (headers_sent()) {
        $_SESSION['Cookies'][] = [$key => [$value, $time]];
    } else {
        setcookie($key, $value, time() + $time, '/', SITE, HTTPS, true);
    }
}
```

Granted SITE and HTTPS are global constants